# Magento2 reindex all indexes once a week by cron

Tags: magento2, cron, reindex

In backend all indexes are set Update by Schedule. But it works every minute. 
How can I set reindex all once a week?

Comment: Could you let me know how to set your cronjob for re-index? Did you set time correctly?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we should not do that. For example: when editing a product price, we need to wait a week for a new price. Don’t try to do that.

Comment: Also when you add a product it takes maximum a week to get visible

Comment: @FrankGroot your issue is that a product will get visible after a week?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh magento reindex indexed only new products or ALL ?
I need reindex only new products.

Comment: Magento will reindex all products.